# what does the numpy vander function do and why use it in a regression?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, regression

I am trying to under the code written in this [module](https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/88477497/) to understand cointegration.

However when I step through the code I am confused by the last line in the section of code below. I have read the documentation of the vander function however I don't really understand what the function is doing?

```
 def detrend(y, order):
    if order == -1:
       return y
    return OLS(y, np.vander(np.linspace(-1, 1, len(y)), order + 1)).fit().resid
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function np.vander returns an array where  the first column is x^(N-1), the second x^(N-2) and so forth. Look this example:

```
x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 5])
N = 3
np.vander(x, N)

array([[ 1,  1,  1],
   [ 4,  2,  1],
   [ 9,  3,  1],
   [25,  5,  1]])
```

In your code N= order+1 and X=np.linspace(-1, 1, len(y)).
You can use also "increasing=True" where the first column is x^(0), the second x^(1) and so forth and the last x^(N-1).